# External Microphone Shown, Enabled, but no Input

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm having trouble using my microphone on Ubuntu 18.04; it's combined with a headphone but has two separate jacks. It works perfectly on Windows. I've plugged it into several ports and the device always shows in sound, pavucontrol, and alsamixer. The volume is up; the microphone is unmuted in all three. pacmd tells me the device is enabled and with full volume. I've changed the volume and muted and unmuted the device in as many ways as I can think of, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

[image]

It is of note that on alsamixer the default audio card does not contain the input; the card shown in this picture is number two.

[image]

Here's an image from pacmd.

[image]

I'm really stuck. I've searched everywhere and I can't find a thing. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested your microphone on another computer/device?

Comment: Yes; it works perfectly. Edited.

Comment: Review:  Ubuntu 18.04 is still in test and unsupported outside of testing channels, this is *off-topic* on this site (until its release)